# new_df = df1[df2['pin'].isin(df1['vpin'])] UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, isin

I'm getting the following warning while executing this line
new_df = df1[df2['pin'].isin(df1['vpin'])]
UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.

The df1 and df2 has only one similar column and they do not have same number of rows.
I want to filter df1 based on the column in df2. If df2.pin is in df1.vpin I want those rows.
There are multiple rows in df1 for same df2.pin and I want to retrieve them all.

| pin | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |

| vpin | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cell 2 |
| 1 | Cell 4 |

The command is working. I'm trying to overcome the warning.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to use `df2['pin'].isin(df1['vpin'])` as a boolean mask to index `df1` as this mean will have the indices of `df2`, thus the reindexing performed by pandas.

Use instead:

```
new_df = df1[df1['vpin'].isin(df2['pin'])]
```